# Regex matching of character class and special conditions on certain other conditions

Tags: regex, matching

I want to match a section of a string that contains certain characters repeated, along with certain other characters only given a certain criteria. For instance matching characters a-z contained in angle brackets and numbers only if the number is preceeded by a plus.

Matching `<abcde>` to `abcde`.

`<abcde1>` should not match anything.

Matching `<abcde+1>` to `abcde+1`
Matching `<abcde+1asd+2+3+4as>` to `abcde+1asd+2+3+4as`

`<abcde+>` should not match anything.

The regex I've tried is `<([a-z]|(\+(?=[0-9])|[0-9](?<=[\+])))*>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=<)(?:[a-zA-Z]+(?:\+\d+)*)+[a-zA-Z]*(?=>)
<((?:[a-zA-Z]+(?:\+\d+)*)+[a-zA-Z]*)>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bI1Mto/2). *Details*:

- `(?<=<)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a `<` char immediately on the left
- `(?:[a-zA-Z]+(?:\+\d+)*)+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more letters
  - `(?:\+\d+)*` - zero or more sequences of `+` and one or more digits
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - one or more ASCII letters
- `(?=>)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `>` char immediately on the right.

Comment: this wasn't stated clearly in the question but additionally, any further instance of +1 and characters should also be accounted. Essentially it should be like a character class including +1, +2, +3, so on